# Cinematic Wallpaper for Pixel 7 NOT WORKING

Tags: pixel, google-workspace, google-people-api, google-pixel

I am using Pixel 7, I am facing an issue, i can't see the cinematic wallpaper option when i set wallpapers. Tried everything from the internet making a cinematic wallpaper in google photos, updating all the google apps, no solution. I am currently running on Android 14 Beta.

Thank You.

Comment: Please see [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on the type of questions to ask on StackOverflow.